# Why is my Memory sometimes 4.5 bytes and some times 6 bytes?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Why is my MacBook Pro 2015 model core i5's memory sometimes 4.5 bytes and some times 6 bytes?

I ran this code in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char ch[] = "Hello World!";
char *p1 = "Hello World!";

printf("%p %s\n", &ch , ch);

printf("size of = %lu bytes\n", sizeof(&ch));

printf("%p %s\n", p1, p1);

printf("size of = %lu bytes\n", sizeof(p1));

return 0;
}
```

My Terminal Output is

```
0x7ffee8f54a2b Hello World!
size of = 8 bytes
0x106cabf88 Hello World!
size of = 8 bytes
```

Why do I get a 6 byte memory address in the first case, and 4.5 memory address in the second case?

Comment: Add three `0`s to the front and you got a 6-byte address.

Comment: All leading zeros are dropped. Try to use %X instate of %p.

Comment: `ch` is located on the stack, the string that `p1` points to is in the text section. They're far apart in memory.

Comment: If you want to know the size of a pointer, use `sizeof`.

Comment: Hey Barmar, thanks for the pointer (pun intended). I updated the code when I used sizeof(). But it's more confusing as it's giving me 8 bytes.

Comment: Also, there is "%zu" for formatting sizes.

Comment: The number of digits in the location address is completely unrelated to the *amount* of memory used. Any more than the house numbers in a street have anything to do with the size of the house, only *where* they are.

Comment: `0x106cabf88` is a perfectly valid 8 bytes value, just like `10` is a perfectly valid 4 bytes value, or `123` is a perfectly valid 128 bytes value.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "6 byte memory address" and especially "4.5 memory address"?

Comment: Ok I see, but shouldn't it be similar if 0x + 12 digits stores the pointer for ch. Shouldn't it be the same 0x + 12 digits store pointer for p? I consistently only get 0x + 9 digits. What's up with that?

Comment: @DevO `%X` is for `int`.  `%p` is for `void *`.  Suggesting a non-matching specifier leads to troubles.

Comment: Barmar's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164531/why-is-my-memory-sometimes-4-5-bytes-and-some-times-6-bytes#comment108204554_61164531) and an answer explain that. `%p` is not showing the memory *content* but its *location*.

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
printf("%p %s\n", &ch , ch);
```

there is outputted the address of the variable ch with the automatic storage duration declared like

```
char ch[] = "Hello World!";
```

In this statement

```
printf("%p %s\n", p1, p1);
```

there is outputted the value stored in the pointer `p1` that is the address of the first character of the string literal "Hello World!" that is stored in the static memory (memory with the static storage duration).

So you are outputting addresses of different kinds of memory.

In the second case the value of the address is less than in the first case. Leading zeroes are not outputted though the both pointers have the same size of 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get a 6 byte memory address in the first case, and 4.5 memory address in the second case?

The format of `"%p"` is implementation dependent.  OP's system is simple omitting leading zero hex-digits.

The memory address (pointers) both take up the same size: 8 bytes (or perhaps more - but the same).

The are different area of memory [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164531/why-is-my-memory-sometimes-4-5-bytes-and-some-times-6-bytes/61164747#comment108204554_61164531).